# what is do(keyword) c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, keyword

I never knew there was a keyword, do, in c++!
what is it?

Comment: [Related] Works the same way it does in C#, Java, Python, PHP, ... pretty much everywhere.

Comment: Da doo ron ron ron, da doo ron ruuunn.  The Crystal Balls.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a loop:

```
do {
...
} while(someCondition);
```

Answer (score 9):

Well its used with **while** keyword:

```
do {
   ...
} while(foo)
```

Unlike a **for** loop a **do-while** loop is always executed **at-least once**.

Also note that **do { } while(0)** is a commonly used idiom in Linux kernel, see [this](http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/DoWhile0) faq for details.

Answer (score 5):

It is a looping tool. Sometimes you need a loop that executes *at least once*. This is when you use a loop such as

```
do {
/* Code will always be executed at least once */
/* something needed to be done once or more times */
} while ( /* not done /* )
```

where as

```
while( /* not done */) {
 /* this code may never be executed */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is same a while statement (except for the syntax), however if you use a do..while loop, it gurantees that the loop is executed atleast once even if the condition specified in while doesn't satisfy.

Answer (score 1):

do keyword is used in the do...while loops. It is like the while loop, the difference is that in the do...while loop condition is checked after the loop execution.

Answer (score 0):

`do while` is usable to executes a statement repeatedly until the specified termination condition (the expression) evaluates to zero.

> do    statement    while ( expression
>   ) ;

[look at this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0kk5few.aspx)